# Transform zeros of x number of rows in NA in R

Tags: r

In my data frame I have only zeros up until row 1500 in the column nr.flights, that I want to transform to NA's (I have no data available about the nr.flights for the first 1500 rows). There are other values from row 1500 onwards that are zero but that needs to remain zero.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
Date           AD     Runway    MTOW    nr.flights
2008-01-01     A       18        376      0
2008-01-01     A       18        376      0    
2008-01-01     D       36        190      0
2008-01-02     D       09        150      2
2008-01-02     A       36        280      1
2008-01-02     A       36        280      1
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
Date           AD     Runway    MTOW    nr.flights
2008-01-01     A       18        376      NA
2008-01-01     A       18        376      NA
2008-01-01     D       36        190      NA
2008-01-02     D       09        150      2
2008-01-02     A       36        280      1
2008-01-02     A       36        280      1
```

So far I've only managed to change the entire column into either NA's or zeros, but I want to have both of these in there. Any help would be much appreciated!

To reproduce:

```
df <- data.frame(Date=c("2008-01-01","2008-01-01","2008-01-01","2008-01- 02","2008-01-02","2008-01-02"),
          AD = c("A", "A", "D", "D", "A", "A"), Runway = c(18, 18, 36, 09, 36,36), 
          MTOW = c(376, 376, 190, 150, 280, 280), nr.flights = c(0,0,0,2,1,1))
```

Comment: How about `df$nr.flights[df$nr.flights == 0] <- NA`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
is.na(df$nr.flights[1:1500])[df$nr.flights[1:1500] == 0] <- TRUE
```

It works by isolating the values equal to 0, then assign the `NA` status to `TRUE`. This is typically the safer option compared to `df[mysubset] <- NA`.

```
df
        Date AD Runway MTOW nr.flights
1 2008-01-01  A     18  376         NA
2 2008-01-01  A     18  376         NA
3 2008-01-01  D     36  190         NA
4 2008-01-02  D      9  150          2
5 2008-01-02  A     36  280          1
6 2008-01-02  A     36  280          1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! The problem is that I have other values that are zero from row 1500 onwards that need to remain zero. And in this case these will be changed as wel I think. I suppose I didn't explain this very well clear in the question, apologies for that. I'll put it up in the description. Thanks again though!

Comment: I edited the answer. Just add `[1:1500]` to work on those values only.

Comment: Yes it works now! Can't believe I spent so much time figuring this out... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[1:.N <=1500 & !nr.flights, nr.flights := NA]
df
#          Date AD Runway MTOW nr.flights
#1:  2008-01-01  A     18  376         NA
#2:  2008-01-01  A     18  376         NA
#3:  2008-01-01  D     36  190         NA
#4: 2008-01- 02  D      9  150          2
#5:  2008-01-02  A     36  280          1
#6:  2008-01-02  A     36  280          1
```